# Ending an Android Service started by fragment

Tags: java, android, service

I am trying to end a service started by my fragment.

I tried to end the service in onDestroyView but my service stopped when i switched fragments.
I need it to stop when my application closes.

How do I stop service in onDestroy of the activity containing the fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    stopService(new Intent(this, YourService.class));

}
```